# TensorFlow Using Ints as categorical variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In creating a basic Neural network model is it possible to use int's directly as categorical variables?
That is..
I have a data table that looks like:

```
    agegrp  gender  race    marital_status  region  ccs1    ccs2    ccs3    ccs4    ccs5
0   281     285     297     288             309     129     131     197     211     212
1   281     285     297     291             306     145     117     121     197     236
2   281     284     297     288             306     108     130     259     109     129
3   281     285     297     291             306      55     661      52     257     206
4   281     285     297     288             309      226    259      60     158     161
```

Where ccs5 is the target label column
In reading Francois Chollet's book (Deep Learning With Python, MEAP, page 101-103) he uses sparse_categorical_crossentropy  loss with the an int label in his Reuters classification example..

However I cannot find any reference to using Categorical variables this way.. I'm hoping to avoid exploding that data via one hot encoding since there are so many values in the data columns, or creating dummies.. But maybe this is not possible?

The problem we are attempting to model is taking the base demographic data agegroup, gender,race marital status region and the sequential occurrence of diagnosis code (the ccs codes some 250 or so) to predict the 5th diagnosis code. We have plenty of data..

Any advice or pointers for dealing with integer categorical varibles in the best manner much appreciated!

Comment: Is this part of Keras? I don't think sparse_categorical_crossentropy is in the tensorflow api.

Comment: Yes it seems to be part of Keras

Comment: I don't know anything about keras but in tensorflow you never have to use one hot encodings

Comment: So how to approach?? I'm not getting it in the TF doc?

Comment: You would use this function https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy

Comment: mmm.. in the doc it says THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2016-12-30. Instructions for updating: Use tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead. I'm not yet sure that I see that it handles the column values (as distinguished from the labels) as categorical and not scalar?

Comment: Use sparse_softmax_cross_entropy and observe that it is asking for the labels as categorical and not as one hot.

Comment: awesome thanks for the pointers!